# JInternal Frame Components Not Initializing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hello I'm newish to Java and have recently attempted to go from using netbeans IDE to using raw code for making my JIternalFrames, but it displays either with no components or not at all.

To correct the issue I have attempted to move around the order in which I set up components for example I originally had it as initvariables > addcomponentstopanes > setsizes/text > setvisible, i've also tried using repaint() and revalidate() to no avail.

```
package tester;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestChunk extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame 
{

    JInternalFrame consumeWindow;
    JScrollPane coScrollPane;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton eatBerriesButton, eatMushroomsButton, eatFishButton;

    public void startComponents()
    {
        consumeWindow = new JInternalFrame("Consume Panel");
        panel = new JPanel();
        eatBerriesButton = new JButton();
        eatMushroomsButton = new JButton();
        eatFishButton = new JButton();
        GridLayout myLayout;

        consumeWindow.setBorder(null);
        consumeWindow.setResizable(true);
        myLayout = new GridLayout(0, 3, 10, 5);
        panel.setLayout(myLayout);

        consumeWindow.setSize(500, 325);
        panel.setSize(500, 650);
        eatBerriesButton.setBounds(5, 5, 150, 50);
        eatMushroomsButton.setBounds(5, 60, 150, 50);
        eatFishButton.setBounds(5, 105, 150, 50);

        panel.add(eatMushroomsButton);
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
        panel.add(eatBerriesButton);
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
        panel.add(eatFishButton);
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();

        coScrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        coScrollPane.setSize(500, 325);
        coScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        coScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        consumeWindow.setContentPane(coScrollPane);
        consumeWindow.revalidate();
        consumeWindow.repaint();

        consumeWindow.setVisible(true);
        consumeWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

The problem is my newest JInternalFrame (The one written entirely in code) isn't displaying and when I do get it to display it doesn't have any of it's components. The internal frame as it currently is should contain 3 buttons within a JScrollPane with about a 5 gap between each button. (If you'd like more code for clarification feel free to request it).

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Be sure to leave out unnecessary details like setting the font.

Comment: So I should remove the font setting bits is what your suggesting? so it's def not the font setting that's doing it?

Comment: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) would be a good place to start

Comment: `coScrollPane.add(eatFishButton);` is not how you use `JScrollPane`, see [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: "I should remove the font setting bits is what your suggesting?" What is it about the two documents I linked that is unclear?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did remove the text after your first comment I was just unsure if my problem was a result of said code hence my confusion

Comment: *"was a result of said code"* Well, you'll find out when preparing an MRE / SSCCE. Again: **What is it about the two documents I linked that is unclear?**

Comment: Hi guys figured out what I did wrong it I was making a jframe inside a jframe so the frame was never visible as I set it up for the one inside the other